# After my condo shuts off and turns on the main water, how can I avoid dirty water?

Tags: water

Every year my parents' condo in Ontario (Canada) shut off the building's water, just like the quotations below in the morning. They restore it in the late afternoon. ISSUE — after the building reactivates water, the water out of my parent's tap is brown and gritty. Parents must let this dirty water run for  AT LEAST 4 HOURS before the water is clean again.

How can they avoid this filthy water? If the building reactivates the water at 4 PM, what if they wait a few hours before turning their condo unit's taps back on?

[Post #8](https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?threads/clear-water-began-turning-brown-after-plumbers-work.66218/#post-491998)

> Every year in my apartment building in the City, they shut off the building water and clean the water tank on the roof. They get it completely free of dirt and sediment and everything else and flush it thoroughly before they refill it with water and reopen the connection to the building. For whatever reason, the shutting off of the water and turning the water back on stirs up sediment, and the water in the building turns a really gross Brown for about 6 hours, after which it gets lighter, and after which it goes back to its usual perfect clarity.

[Post #2](https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?threads/clear-water-began-turning-brown-after-plumbers-work.66218/#post-491941)

> When the water was turned off and back on, it probably stirred up some sediment in the lines. I think it will clear up after some more water is run through the pipes.

Comment: It is a matter of rinsing out the water tank.  A large tank will take some time, but the more people who open their taps, will make it go faster.  If people wait then it takes longer.  Would remove the faucet strainers/screens first, if any.

Comment: "Would remove the faucet strainers/screens first, if any." Why? Can you elaborate pls?

Comment: If the faucets have strainers they might get clogged if there is sediment, just saves from having to clean them after.

Comment: Would say that 4 hours, seems like the time it would take if only your parents where doing the rinsing.  Condo management should give information on what they have done and why it would take so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add you should run your water to the place that is easiest to take apart and fix.   When a main is shut off a lot of debris is kicked up and calcium and other deposits dislodge.

Sometimes this isn't fully feasible but I try to run my garden hose for 20 mins - there's no filter on it so debris and deposits should just spit out.   I have also ran my laundry room hose into the overflow because it was at the lowest point in the house.

These things for sure help - trust me I had a house where they did stuff on the main 2-3 times a month for 5-6 years...  Had a few shower valves I had to take apart, had faucet screens needing cleaning every couple months and while they were doing it had a toilet jump around like the scene from Goonies... just one toilet in a 4 bathroom house.

Running a hose helps for sure - the water company told me to do this.   It isn't going to solve things 100% though because once water hits your lines it branches out and if pieces are shot out a certain branch running water on another may not effect that all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your condo association is willing put in a filtration system  at the main source then you  either have to **flush the pipes for a minute or two**  (*Not practical for refrigerator supply lines*.)

**OR** Install a filter in your unit.
This can be done if you have one supply pipe coming into your unit as opposed to separate lines that go to individual fixtures.

The condo i live in does this on a regular basis and i just open all fixtures and let them run a few minutes.